# One to One Mapping - Spring Data JPA Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to have a One to One mapping between 2 tables in my spring Data JPA - Spring Boot application . I followed the example at

[One to One Mapping Spring Data Example](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-one-foreignkey-relationship-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)

It runs fine and inserts records in the second table( Book Detail) as well. In my application i need to update the record in the second table multiple times (say no of pages column as in the example).

I am reading the book object and then updating the bookdetail fields and saving it back using the repository(extends CrudRepository).

If I do this 10 times, the bookdetail table is having 10 records for the same book and in the book table it refers to the key value of the last updated bookdetail record for that book. But I need to update the same record in bookdetail. One record in bookdetail for one record in Book.

//This block can get executed for n times in the same thread for same book in //actual application codeflow

```
// book = retrieve from Book repo
            if(book.getBookDetail() == null){
                System.out.println("NO BookDetail ");
                BookDetail bookDetail = new BookDetail();
                bookDetail.set...(123)
                book.setBookDetail(bookDetail);
            }else{ 
                book.getBookDetail().set...(123)
            }
            bookRepo.save(book);
```

What am i doing wrong here.

Adding the entity classes

```
public class Book implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int bookId;


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="detailId")
private BookDetail bookDetail;

//Other fields

//Getter & Setter

}

public class BookDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int detailId;


@Lob
private String data;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="bookDetail")
private Book book;

//Other fields

//Getter & Setter

}
```

Comment: Can you post your entity model classes?

Comment: Updated with the entity classes

Answer (score 0):

```
bookRepo.save(book);
```

Are you sure you want to save book entity and not to update it? And if you want to edit existing book detail, why won't you edit the object that refers to it instead of creating a new one?

Comment: But am not creating a new one everytime its only the first time when the obj is non-existent.

Comment: @oxygenan sorry, I was definitely not paying enough attention. But, does it work the same way if you update entity instead of saving it?

Comment: Do you mean to write a custom method to update? We have only save method in CrudRepository

Comment: @oxygenan didn't know that, I'm not that familiar with Spring Data as I'm using only JPA and JDBC. I think what you're looking for is orphan removal. Could you try to annotate bookDetail field like that @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)?  "If a Child entity is dissociated from its Parent, the Child Foreign Key is set to NULL. If we want to have the Child row deleted as well, we have to use the orphan removal support." quote from here https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/